# Align a label to the right using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, label

I have a label on an ASP.NET page.  Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

What I want it to look like is like this:

[image]

I've tried using a DIV tag, and I've tried using Style="text-align: right" in the `<asp:Label>` tag, neither of which worked.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: As per the first comment, this is all inside a table tag:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" BackColor="#0f6fc6" Height="110px" Width="780px">
   <table style="width:780px">
      <tr>
         <td style="width:90px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFunct" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Function" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
         </td>
         <td style="width:240px">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFunction" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFunction_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="230px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td style="width:120px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Role" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
         </td>
         <td style="width:240px">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="230px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProd" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Prod Tasks" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTask" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTask_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="230px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblOffprod" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Off Prod Tasks" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOffprod" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOffprod_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="230px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPlatform" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" Font-Size="XX-Small" Height="10px" RepeatColumns="2" Visible="false" Width="270px" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" TextAlign="Left">
               <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Facets </asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="1">Non-Facets</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
         </td>
         <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblAccountName" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White" Visible="true" Style="text-align: right"></asp:Label>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: This has a lot less to do with ASP.NET and a lot more to do with HTML/CSS.  What is the actual HTML here?  What styles are currently applied to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:right">
    <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could put the label in a div and in the label tag put `style="float:left"`.

```
<div>
    <asp:label ID="myLabel" runat="server" style="float:right"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Edit:

Also, for completeness, as mentioned by Aimal Khan you can use it in the code behind as:

```
myLabel.Attributes.Add("Style", "float: right");
```

Comment: used it in Code Behind as this --- createDiv2.Attributes.Add("Style", "float:right;"); --

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Cheers